# Left outer join with multiple conditions - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, left-join

I'm running into some problems with a very simple query. I figure that it must be because of an incorrect assumption about how SQL queries work.
I'm trying to write a simple LEFT OUTER JOIN query using the following tables:

```
tmtrip_viewer( tmtrip_id, tmuser_id )      -> FKs: (tmtrip.id, tmuser.id)
Values: ( 6, 2 )
        ( 6, 3 )
        ( 7, 4 )

tmtrip( id, ...)
Values: (1, ...)
        (2, ...)
        (3, ...)
        (4, ...)

tmuser(id, username, ...)
Values: (1, user1)
        (2, user2)
        (3, user3)
        (4, user4)
```

What I want to do is:
  Display alls `id` from `tmuser` table given the following conditions:
  - That the id != '1'
  - That the id is NOT in table `tmtrip_viewer` where tmtrip_viewer.tmtrip_id = 7.

Basically, I want to get all the users that are not viewing the tmtrip with tmtrip_id = 7 (except the logged in user ..id='1').

I have formulated the following query, but it does not behave as desired:

```
SELECT a.`id`, a.`username` FROM 
`tmuser` a LEFT OUTER JOIN `tmtrip_viewer` b
ON a.`id` = b.`tmuser_id` AND b.`tmtrip_id` = '7'
WHERE a.id <> '1'
```

Why is this not working? What would be the right way to do this?

Comment: In what way is it not working?  What results are you getting that are incorrect?

Comment: change `b.'tmtrip_id' <> '7'`  instead of = as you said NOT in table with ID 7.  assuming you want IDs 2,3 in expected result.

Comment: That isn't correct - OP wants a list of all users that aren't viewing trip 7 - with your suggestion if a user was viewing both trip 6 and trip 7, they'd still show one record.  I don't think that's what OP wants.

Comment: @jim This is true perhaps a subquery is needed.

Comment: @jim.. It was showing all id's in tmtrip_id = '7'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `AND b.tmtrip_id IS NULL` to your `WHERE`. Your query is getting all tmusers and their "trip 7" info if they have any; this will reduce the results to only the ones that had no "trip 7" info.

Comment: That only works for users that have at least one trip being viewed.  If they don't have any trips being viewed, then that user wouldn't show with your suggestion.

Comment: It is only if they don't have any trip 7's being viewed that they show. Which is what the question is asking for as far as I can tell. Users without any trips at all would still be included. (The WHERE occurs after the JOIN....sort of; which is why I personally prefer putting such conditions in a HAVING, even without using aggregation.)

Comment: Sorry, I thought it over again and since that tmtrip_id = 7 is in the left join predicate, you're right, your approach would work still for users that don't have any trips.  My bad.

Comment: @Uueerdo This works. I removed the OUTER and made it just a LEFT JOIN.. idk if that matters at all.

Comment: @JeanAlesi OUTER doesn't matter, it is optional (at least in MySQL), so choosing to include it is a matter of style. Personally, I prefer to omit it since it is redundant; there is no such thing as a "LEFT INNER"

Comment: @that explains a lot.. I always assumed that OUTER automatically added "WHERE tableB.column IS NULL" based on what came after the "ON" condition (namely tableA.column = tableB.column)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you want.

It would show one record for each user that doesn't have ID = 1 and also doesn't have a record in tm_tripviewer with tmtrip_id = 7.

```
SELECT id, username
FROM tmuser
WHERE id != 1
AND id NOT IN
(SELECT id FROM tmtrip_viewer WHERE tmtrip_id = 7)
```

Comment: Thank you Jim.. This query works well. Do subqueries affect performance the way a "for loop" would?